# Using header(Location) and filling select box

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I'm using a php for loop to fill my select box with the years from 1900 to 2013 and echoing out like

```
for ($value = 1900; $value <= 2013; $value++)                       
{
   echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
}
```

That is what makes my header('Location: index.php') not working. When I comment the select box filling lines out, it works.

So my question is, how can I fill the select boxes and still have header(Location) to work?

Do I need to manually write

```
    <option value='1900'>1900</option>
    <option value='1901'>1901</option>
    <option value='1902'>1902</option>
```

and so on..

Comment: Why do you want to output your options when you redirect anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`header(Location)` only works if there has nothing else been printed.

EDIT: You could add following line to your `<head>`-section:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://your_url.com/">`

Answer (score -1):

Use `echo '<script>window.location='index.php'</script>';`

instead of header

Comment: header redirect do not work, when something is echoed prior to it.

Comment: Is js the only solution? Because I would prefer not to use it, since the user can turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

You need to print:

```
'<script>window.location='index.php'</script>';
```

instead of `header`.